# Are the $H$ and $M$ fields inversely proportional?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics

I am following a course in Statistical Physics. One exercise starts as follows:

> **Rushbrooke Inequality.**
> Consider the Helmholtz free energy per site $f(T,M)$ for a magnetic system subject to a field in the thermodynamic limit. We have that the differential of this Helmholtz free energy is given by $df=HdM-SdT$. Then the magnetization per site is given by
> $$M=-\left(\frac{df}{dH}\right)_T.$$

I am not sure if this is correct, because this implies that the $M$ and $H$ fields are inversely proportional. That is, the product $MH$ is constant for fixed temperature $T$. If that is really true, then why can't I find it anywhere on the internet? And when $H$ goes to zero, does $M$ really diverge to infinity?

Here is my derivation: firstly, from $df=HdM-SdT$ we obtain $H=\left(\frac{df}{dM}\right)_T$.
Also $f$ is a function of $M,T$ and $M$ is a function of $H,T$. Therefore the chain rule gives us
$$\left(\frac{df}{dH}\right)_T=\left(\frac{df}{dM}\right)_T\cdot \left(\frac{dM}{dH}\right)_T.$$
We know two of these derivatives, so we can substitute them:
$$-M=H\cdot \left(\frac{dM}{dH}\right)_T,$$
hence
$$\left(\frac{dM}{dH}\right)_T=-\frac MH.$$

Now we can calculate the following derivative:
$$\left(\frac{dHM}{dH}\right)_T=M+H\left(\frac{dM}{dH}\right)_T=M+H\cdot-\frac MH=0.$$

At least, the formula for the Helmholz energy seems to be correct: I checked that [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/787202/connection-helmholtz-free-energy-and-h-m-b-fields).

Comment: That equation for $M$ seems strange. By changing variables to $F(T, H)$ I get that $\partial F / \partial H |_T = H \partial M / \partial H |_T$.

Comment: I agree that that is a strange equation. However, it also appears on this Wikipedia page in the definition of M: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rushbrooke_inequality

Answer (score 2):

Electrodynamics says that if one increases the magnetic field, then the energy changes as $dE=H\,dB/(4\pi)$, where $B=H+4\pi M$. In the bulk we use $H$ (instead of $B$) as independent variable. So, first we write
$$dF(T,B)=-S\,dT-p\,dV+\mu\,dN+\frac{1}{4\pi}H\,dB.$$
and then we have
$$\mathcal{F}(T,H)=F(T,B)-\frac{1}{8\pi}H^2-HM,$$
which gives
$$d\mathcal{F}(T,H)=-S\,dT-p\,dV+\mu\,dN-M\,dH.$$
From this expression, we see that
$$M=-\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial H}\right)_T.$$
In the limit of vanishing $H$, we have
$$M\sim - \left.\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial H}\right|_{H\rightarrow 0}\propto(-t)^{\beta},\quad t=\frac{T-T_c}{T_c}.$$

You can find the discussion of Rushbrooke scaling law in the statistical physics lecture notes by G. Blatter or in the very first chapters of "Introduction to the Functional Renormalization Group".

Comment: So the answer would be “no, they are not inversely proportional”

Comment: Could you provide a link to the lecture notes by Blatter? I can not find them.

Comment: @Riemann , "Intro to FRG" is more comprehensive. If you cannot find G. Blatter notes (now I also cannot find them) and avoid my reference to FRG book, you can check book "Scale invariane" by A. Lesne & M. Lagues (chap. 3, sect. 3.2) for discussion of Rushbrooke scaling law.

Comment: Thank you, I have no access to “Intro to FRG”.

Comment: However, the book Scale Invariance says in a footnote that the ‘right free energy’ to consider is more like the gibbs energy than the helmholz energy. That reinforces the idea that there is indeed something wrong with the exercise in my course, and with Wikipedia.

Comment: @Riemann https://home.itp.ac.ru/~burmi/HSE/Lectures-StatPhys-temp.pdf (p. 77, sect. 3.2.2). May be it will be helpful

Comment: Yes, Equation 3.30 and below give the same conclusion as your answer

Comment: Your answer should state explicitly that it is not the same function that provides $M$ if derived wrt $H$ and $H$ if derived wrt to $M$. Thus explaining why the "derivation" in the question is false. Moreover, the function $\cal F$ is a function of $H$ (and not of the same field in the absence of material) only in some special case (see my answer to this related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/787202/connection-helmholtz-free-energy-and-h-m-b-fields )

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 , yes, I agree with this statement.